# FLOT Data Arrays from MYSQL JQuery call

Tags: php, mysql, flot

I have a FLOT pie chart that I need to dynamically create. I am calling the data via JSON PHP MYSQL...

```
 $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'includes/ajax/ajax-chart-client-services.php', 
  data: "client_id=" + $('#sel_client_id').val() + "&parent=6", 
  dataType: 'json',                      
  success: function(data) {
    graph_data = data;
    //alert(graph_data);
    var plot = $.plot('#chr_services', [graph_data], {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                combine: {
                    color: '#999',
                    threshold: 0.1
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        }
    });     
  }
  });


<? //PHP PAGE HERE
 $flotPieData = array();

$currentSeries = array();                                       
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    $currentSeries["label"] = $row['strProductCatName'];
   $currentSeries["data"] = array();
   $currentSeries["data"][] = array(1,(int)$row['iqt']); //push 
   $flotPieData[] = $currentSeries;
}

//$flotPieData[] = $currentSeries;  
echo json_encode($flotPieData);
exit();
?>
```

The above PHP script returns the following values..

> [{"label":"Windows Development","data":[["1","4"]]},{"label":"Handheld Development","data":[["1","2"]]},{"label":"Printing","data":[["1","1"]]}]

The chart does not show anything. but if I look at the data return it is perfect?

Anyideas anyone?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for possible errors?

Comment: Yes I have, but no errors reported. I even tried changing the data array values from strings to numbers. still does not work

Comment: if I return only ONE set of array value . [{"label":"Printing","data":[[1,1]]}], an remove the [] from my returned ajax query ..$.plot('#chr_services', graph_data,.. i get a pie with obviously one value???

Comment: Your `graph_data` is already an array but you pass `[graph_data]` to the plot function. What happens if you just change that? And could you please build a fiddle, code snippet etc. to show your problem.

Comment: Your data is strings: `"data":[["1","2"]]`, `1` and `2` are quoted.  Not sure why since you cast to `int` before `json_encode` (I know certain version of PHP have problems with this).  Maybe try `echo json_encode($flotPieData,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I remove the [] from [graph_data], and it worked!